# Showing Slide Count with Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I would like to show the slide count as `2 of 10` on my slider. How do I make it work with the transitions `3 of 10`, `4 of 10` (as the slider moves with slides) & `7 of 10` (if the corresponding thumbnail was clicked)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have the current slide no as `current_slide_no = jQuery('#nivo-slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide;` Add 1 to it as index starts from 0.

Use `afterChange` attribute to change the current slide number while initializing the NIVO slider.

So, I got it working by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var total = jQuery('#nivo-slider img').length;
        var current_slide_no = 1; // garbage
        // var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
        jQuery('#nivo-slider').nivoSlider({
            effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown,slideInLeft'
            animSpeed:600, //Slide transition speed
            pauseTime:30000,
            directionNav:false, //Next and Prev
            // directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
            controlNav:true, //1,2,3...
                controlNavThumbs:true, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
            controlNavThumbsFromRel:true, //Use image rel for thumbs
            pauseOnHover:false, //Stop animation while hovering
            //captionOpacity:0.3, //Universal caption opacity
            startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
            // keyboardNav:true //Use left and right arrows
            afterChange: function(){
                current_slide_no = jQuery('#nivo-slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide;
                jQuery('#nivo-slider-status > .current-slide').html(current_slide_no+1);
            }
        });
        jQuery('#nivo-slider-status').show();
        jQuery('#nivo-slider-status > .total-slides').html(total);
        current_slide_no = jQuery('#nivo-slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide;
        jQuery('#nivo-slider-status > .current-slide').html(current_slide_no+1);
    });
    </script>
```

and my html (should be outside the NIVO slider DIV) is

```
<div id="nivo-slider-status" class="alignright">
    <span class="current-slide"></span> of <span class="total-slides"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ashframe Thanks for the solution. But I hav an issue: I'm trying to add slide count on a page with multiple sliders, but the total slides was wrong. What can I do?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Make IDs unique for each slider and make sure JS code is targeting the right instances.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look for the clickhandler and or transition event. I haven't used nivo yet but this is the concet you need to do:

```
parent = $('#buttons'); // button container
pages = parent.find('.button').size; // total number of pages

parent.find('.button').click(function(){
  index = parent.index($this) + 1; // this is the the page number

  //do something with these variables
  $('#div1').html(index + ' of ' + pages); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that Nivo slider provides simple way of retrieving the current slide number and then I used it to calculate the correct value after every slide change.