# Nivo Slider: Skype.com Carousel Effect - Change CSS for Nav based on CurrentSlide

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel, nivo-slider

I have been trying to create a slider based on Nivo Slider that looks and functions similar to the Carousel found at http://www.skype.com/intl/en/home

I have viewed questions by [Ashfame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441617/showing-slide-count-with-nivo-slider) and by [Chris_Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947308/change-css-based-on-nivo-slider-current-image), however I have been going round in circles for most of the weekend. Now back at square one and starting from the basics.

Thus far I have managed to get the navigation working such that mouseenter on a particular nav item triggers nivo-controlNav to display the correct slide and pauses the slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$("ul#nav_1").mouseenter(
    function () {
       $(".nivo-controlNav a:nth-child(2)").click();
       $('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
    });
</script>
```

I also created a subsequent mouseleave function for the nav items (1,2,3 etc.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul#nav_1,ul#nav_2,ul#nav_3").mouseleave(
     function () {
       $('#slider').data('nivoslider').start();
      });
    </script>
```

I'm now stuck at the part where non-mouse events come in. When the slider loads it should update the nav css to highlight the current nav item selected. Here is what I've got (not a lot I know, but I'm trying).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
       beforeChange: function(){ // this function should load css styles
          var slide_num = $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide;
          function scrollBannerCss () {
             if (slide_num == 1) {
               $("ul#nav_1").css("backgound-color", "blue");
                 }
           }
       },
       afterChange: function(){ // this function should unload css styles
    });
 });
</script>
```

Then the simple html nav menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li id="nav_1">button 1</li>
   <li id="nav_2">button 2</li>
   <li id="nav_3">button 3</li>
</ul>
```

Any help/ideas/musings would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What server platform you using?

Comment: @PaulSullivan would that matter considering this is client side javascript?

Comment: @PaulSullivan if I catch your drift, I'm using the standalone jquery plugin on a custom site (i.e. not using a WordPress plugin)...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old but you may want to look at http://www.agilecarousel.com/.

http://www.agilecarousel.com/flavor_3.htm is the exact thing you are talking about, considering skype.com today is the same thing you saw two months ago.

Comment: Hi Jason. I know my comment here is way over due, but thanks for the tip!