# Nivo Slider Event Trigger with JQuery

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, slider, nivo-slider

I've found answers to problems here a number of times and it seems like a really great community! I am currently using the Nivo slider for a project for a client:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

I also have 3 image button on the page that have animations on hover using JQuery. On hover the button will change it's background image and slightly animate.

My client wants this animation to synchronize with the last slide of the Nivo slider, meaning the animation will occur when the last slide fades in, and the animation will deactivate when the slider starts over.

I have the animation working, but the problem is, the Nivo options won't allow you to trigger an event on a specific slide, or at least not that I can figure out.

I am using the Nivo options beforeChange to start the event, and slideshowEnd to deactivate the event. The problem is, beforeChange makes the animation activate after the first slide and I can't figure out how to make it trigger before the last slide.

This is the code I am using:

```
beforeChange: function(){ 
            $('a.shop').animate({"margin-top": "-15px"}, "400");
            $('a.shop').css("background", "url(images/shop_button_hov.png) top center no-repeat");
        },
        slideshowEnd: function(){
            $('a.shop').animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, "400");
            $('a.shop').css("background", "url(images/shop_button.png) top center no-repeat");
        }
```

I am not really a JQuery expert, I can use it and make slight edits, but I'm far from able to make my own functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to get the current slide

```
$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide;
```

here is the solution - it should work. i haven't tested it.

```
beforeChange: function(){ 
    var totalSlides = $('#slider img').length;
    var currentSlide = $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide;

    /* check if the slide to come is  the last slide */
    if(currentSlide == (totalSlides - 2))
    {
         $('a.shop').animate({"margin-top": "-15px"}, "400");
         $('a.shop').css("background", "url(images/shop_button_hov.png) top center no-  repeat");
     }

 },
 slideshowEnd: function(){
     $('a.shop').animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, "400");
     $('a.shop').css("background", "url(images/shop_button.png) top center no-repeat");
 }
```

also check this SO Question
[Showing Slide Count with Nivo Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441617/showing-slide-count-with-nivo-slider)