# I would like nivo to show CurrentSlide out of slide amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, nivo-slider

I would like to show the slide count as 2 of 10 on my slider.

I have tried a few ways to go about it but all have failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing Slide Count with Nivo Slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441617/showing-slide-count-with-nivo-slider)